# Parsec parse string `sepBy` endline

Tags: haskell, parsec

I have faced with strange behavior of `parsec` in case of parsing simple strings

The strings example is:

```
  1 C1           1.1650     2.7470    -0.1840 ca         1 MOL       0.408200
  2 N1          -0.0550     2.1750    -0.0380 nb         1 MOL      -0.665000
  3 C2          -0.2180     0.8450     0.1920 ca         1 MOL       0.450600
  4 C3          -1.6310     0.3330     0.3310 c3         1 MOL      -0.140700
```

My parser is

```
atom = do
    str <- optional spaces *> (many1 $ (letter <|> digit <|> oneOf "-+.")) `sepBy` spaces

    let id = read $ head str :: Int
    let charge = (read.head.reverse) str :: Double    
    return (id,(str !! 1),charge)

records = atom `sepEndBy1` newline
```

I need to parse each string with `atom` parser. If I use only atom parser to a line it works.

But if try to use `records` parser, it looks like the first atom parser eats the whole string. So I have `(1,C1,-0.140700)` instead of array `[(1,C1,-0.408200),(2,N1,0.665000)]` etc.

P.S. I can't understand at all how `parsec`  can traverse a line with `\n` symbols at all, in this case. For example if we have

```
onlyForTest = (many1 $ (letter <|> digit <|> oneOf "-+.")) `sepBy` spaces
```

and test such example:

```
*Main> parseTest onlyForTest  "bla bl\na bla"
```

Output:

```
["bla","bl","a","bla"]
```

But `\n` symbol is not a separator in `sepBy`!

Comment: I thing the problem is that `spaces` accepts not only space character but and tab, newline etc. That's why `atom` accept all string.

Comment: Yes, it looks like that

Comment: `spaces` designed by the `isSapace` function and it does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @freestyle said, `spaces` uses [`Data.Char.isSpace`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:isSpace) to determine if a character should be consumed, and that includes both `\n` and `\r`.

Use `oneOf " \t"` instead of `spaces` and `endOfLine` instead of `newline`. Oh, and `optional` is extraneous in `optional spaces`, because `spaces` consume *zero or more* characters.